# Why hovering over second sub list item loses the focus

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n3tzbn4o/3/

Partial CSS:

```
/* Menu */
.menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When hovering over `Menu 3` > '2015' > `Assesments not submitted` it goes to the next menu but doesn't happen here: https://jsfiddle.net/n3tzbn4o/4/ when the second sub menu doesn't have another sub menu.

How can I resolve the issue.

Comment: That's probably because the lowest submenu is overlapped by the higher one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `opacity` to show and hide your menu, and I would suggest using `display` to show and hide it. When you use `opacity:0;` the element is still rendered out (it's just invisible) which means it is responding to hover events. `display:none;` is not rendered out and will not take up space in the DOM.

Change these 2 styles:

```
.menu2 ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 185px;
    /*opacity:0;*/
    display:none;
    ...
}
.menu2 li:hover > ul { /*opacity:1;*/ display:block; }
```

See this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3tzbn4o/6/)

Comment: I see. I wanted the fade in/out effect. I guess I will resort to JQuery for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add z-index here:

```
.menu2 li:hover > ul { 
  opacity: 1; 
  z-index:99999; // <- added
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n3tzbn4o/5/)

Comment: The menu stays for a few seconds before taking focus on the next menu :/